# Which regression and correlation to use?

Tags: regression

I have a database of patients with their heart rate before and after surgery. I would like to do a few analyses:

1. Define a threshold value for an optimal heart rate (i.e., above which there is a significant risk of post operative complications).
2. Test this hypothesis: Does increasing heart rate increase chances of post operative complications?
3. If no 2 is true, then describe the increase in risk of post operative outcomes as heart rate increases. For example, I want to say for every 10 beat per minute increase in heart rate, the relative risk of post operative complications increases by 10%.

What type of regression or tests would be suitable for the analyses above?

Comment: From a purely logical standpoint, note that #1 depends on #2 being true.

Comment: As far as I understand binary logistic regression would be good to use. And t-test to compare the mean heart rate of patients who had a post-op complication and those who didn't. Is that correct?

Comment: Not sure where the post-Heart rate fits in. How are "post operative complications" measured? Is it measured before or after measuring post-heart rate?

Comment: Post operative complication is heart attack, measured by another hormone. It's measured at the same time as the heart rate. Every time patient's heart rate is taken, their blood test is also taken, which measures the level of hormone which serves as a marker for heart attack.

Comment: In the first sentence you said it like the hormone measures heart attack, but it only predicts heart attack, right? Do you have data on whether they had a heart attack? If yes, then logistic regression is the way to go.

Comment: t-test, in a way, is the same thing as binary logistic regression with one numerical predictor. So the t-test would be redundant. Logistic reg is better since you can use multiple predictors, plus your main DV is the post op complication, making interpretation more clear

Answer (score 2):

I would use logistic regression. So your model would be: log(odds) = X(bpm) + Z(confounders) for #3 or log(odds) = X(bpm># yes/no) + Z(confounders) for #1.

**#1 & #3 are ways of looking at #2. In #3 you are assuming linearity (log-linearity with logistic regression), and in #1 you are assuming a sudden shift in risk/odds. If you don't know that the risk/odds are linear, you should probably look at categories of bpm first. And you should probably have some justification for the categories you examine.

Comment: it is unlikely to be linear, you'll likely have to do one of these to heart rate: (1) pre-specify categories (2) quintiles (3) restricted cubic splines. For face-validity you'll want some measure of blood pressure (MAP) and there may be an interaction between these two variables that could complicate analysis.